# Issues running stylelint from CLI

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, stylelint

I'm trying to run stylelint plugin in one of my projects ( )
I don't wanna use gulp but just an npm script (I'm currently doing that with esLint) but I'm getting a "cannot find module" error everytime I run the script.

This is the error:

```
> stylelint 'src/*.scss'

module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'signal-exit'
```

I tried installing that module 'signal-exit' from npm but it is still failing.

Has anyone had this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in stylelint 9.1.0, please update to stylelint 9.1.1

https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/releases/tag/9.1.1